# How to append to the div in babeljs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Using this always updates the html but doesn't append to it.

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      hello
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("emails-view-content"));
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  
  root.render(<App/>);
}
```

I want to write hello 3 times instaed of just one.

Comment: add 3 hellos in your App component?

Comment: You should probably go back and [read how React works](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

`App` should be the component that adds the "hello" statements to the HTML.

*How* you do that is entirely up to you but here's a simple example. It uses a separate `<Hello>` component. `App` receives a number in its props which it uses to create an array of `<Hello>` components which are then rendered.

```js
function App({ number }) {

  function buildHellos(n) {
    return new Array(n).fill(<Hello />);
  }

  return (
    <div>{buildHellos(+number)}</div>
  );

}

function Hello() {
  return <p>Hello</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App number="3" />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```